# output the childNode value in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

how can i use js to output the value of a childNode with an alert(); function or creating a new element. for example.. have this:

```
<ul id="main">
  <li>
   <h2>Alec</h2>
   <p>NX-01</p>
   <p>command: 2151</p>
  </li>
  <li>simple</li> 
  <li>William</li>
</ul>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById("main");
var values = element.childNodes[1].nodeValue; // the text simple this i want to output
alert('the value is:' + values);
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use its `innerText` property:

```
var element = document.getElementById("main");
var values = element.childNodes[1].innerText;
alert('the value is:' + values);
// Alec NX-01 command: 2151
```

The above should print all the text contents of the first `<li>` element (Alec NX-01 command: 2151)

To further refine it and retrieve the value `Alec` for example, use another `.childNodes[1]`

```
var element = document.getElementById("main");
var values = element.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerText;
alert('the value is:' + values);

// Alec
```

Comment: Two problems: this will be inconsistent between browsers because IE < 9 does not include whitespace-only text nodes in its `childNodes` collection whereas other browsers do. Second, `innerText` is not supported in all browsers (Firefox does not support it, for a start).

Comment: ...not to mention that browsers treat `innerText` differently. Some maintain the whitespace, some don't.

Comment: @MattMcDonald: Indeed, and there are also differences between `textContent` and `innerText` such as handling of the contents of `<script>` elements.

Comment: Read more about the `innerText` propery here: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_node_innertext.asp

Answer (score 3):

Use `.nodeValue` for IE and `.textContent` for other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerText` instead of `nodeValue` to get all the text inside of the `<li>` and it's children.  See here for a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/B7Lvd/

Answer (score 0):

You need to take text nodes containing only whitespace into account. In most browsers these nodes appear as text nodes in the `childNodes` collection of a node, whereas in IE < 9 they are ignored. Therefore you need check the `nodeType` property while iterating through `childNodes`. Also, `nodeValue` will not get you the text within the `<li>` element you're interested in: you need to use the DOM standard `textContent` property (falling back to the similar `innerText` property in browsers that do not support `textContent`).

```
function getChildElement(element, index) {
    var elementCount = 0;
    var child = element.firstChild;

    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType == 1)  { // Node with nodeType 1 is an Element
            if (elementCount == index) {
                return child;
            }
            elementCount++;
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}

var element = document.getElementById("main");
var child = getChildElement(element, 1);
var text = child.textContent || child.innerText;
alert("Found element with text " + text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you possibly looking for this:

```
var values = element.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery would make this a lot easier, but with vanilla javascript you could do it this way.

```
var element = document.getElementById("main");
var values = element.childNodes;

for(var i in values) {
    if(values[i].innerHTML == 'simple') {
        alert('The value is: ' +values[i]);
    }
}
```

Or you can access the children individually with values[0], values[1] etc. The question is slightly difficult to understand, but I think that is what you're looking to do.